# How to get notification for unanswerd question of some one else?

Tags: support, notifications

I am new member here, I will like to know how i will get notification on questions asked by some one else but i am also interested in knowing the answer.

Is that favorite star is that for purpose? I pressed that but i never got notification for those questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a favorite star in order for you to track the question on your profile page. Unfortunately this is not Twitter nor Google+, so you can't get notified on other users question.